# LINQ to SQL hierarchy problem

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, hierarchy

I retrieve a result from SQL Server as

```
ProjectDetailID,ProjectID,ParentID,...,C1,C2,C3,...
```

where C1 implies(=>) companyOne, C2=>CompanyTwo ... etc and dynamically can have 'n' companies

For time being lets consider only 3 companies, So I get :

```
ProjectDetailID,ProjectID,ParentID,C1,C2,C3
10,1,0,NULL,NULL,NULL
10,2,1,NULL,NULL,NULL
10,3,2,90,NULL,NULL
10,4,2,NULL,60,NULL
10,10,1,70,NULL,NULL
10,5,10,20,40,NULL
10,13,2,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

I want from this following result using LINQ (C#)

```
ProjectDetailID,ProjectID,ParentID,C1,C2,C3
10,1,0,180,100,NULL
10,2,1,90,60,NULL
10,3,2,90,NULL,NULL
10,4,2,NULL,60,NULL
10,10,1,90,40,NULL
10,5,10,20,40,NULL
10,13,2,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

The problem is that at parent level i have null value for a company but at its child i have some value, which i keep on adding and have placed that in parent corresponding to that company only.

I am not getting from where to start. Please share your ideas. And i am looking to do this in LINQ using C#

Comment: What are the relations... you need to be much more specific.

Comment: what relations you need ? I have just a LIST<Projects> on which i need to operate

Comment: What are the logics that should create the second list... for me you haven't presented what you are trying to do. A simple solution to your problem is to hard code the result since you're not explaining what you want to do. Are you with me?

Comment: So, explain what your objects look like. How you're accessing them and the relations between them if there are more then one type of object.

Comment: @Tomas Jansson : I 'll rectify my question in some time.But briefly i m just totalling childElements data upto parent.Still I'll Edit my question to be more precise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have a solution to your problem.

I've assumed that the `Project` class has a constructor that enables me to do this:

```
var projects = new List<Project>(new []
{
    new Project(10, 1, 0, null, null, null),
    new Project(10, 2, 1, null, null, null), 
    new Project(10, 3, 2, 90, null, null), 
    new Project(10, 4, 2, null, 60, null), 
    new Project(10, 10, 1, 70, null, null), 
    new Project(10, 5, 10, 20, 40, null), 
    new Project(10, 13, 2, null, null, null), 
});
```

So then the solution looks like this:

```
var traverse = projects.ToLookup(p => p.ParentID);

Func<Project, Func<Project, int?>, int?> rollup = null;

rollup = (p, f) =>
{
    var result = (f(p) ?? 0) + traverse[p.ProjectID].Sum(p2 => rollup(p2, f));
    return result == 0 ? (int?)null : result;
};

var query = 
    projects.Select(p =>
        new Project(
            p.ProjectDetailID,
            p.ProjectID,
            p.ParentID,
            rollup(p, p2 => p2.C1),
            rollup(p, p2 => p2.C2),
            rollup(p, p2 => p2.C3)));
```

The trick to this query is the recursive definition of `rollup`. For it to work the anonymous function must be declared and defined using two statements (ie the definition cannot be inline).

The result matches your second set of data in your question. Hopefully this is what you're after.